# android studio Launching 'app' on No Devices - The app is unable to install

Tags: java, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I ran my app few times on my physical device, and it wroked perfectly. Now i'm trying to run the app on virtual device. Not showing any issues in every time, but the app was not installed on the virtual device. I want to emphasize that it worked before I tried on the physical device. When i press the "Run" window, it shows a message: "Launching 'app' on No Devices".

Then i tried to delet all the virtual devices and set new devices. Still the same message.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, Android Studio has a problem in detecting virtual devices! check the AVD Manager window again, and also, check the module you want to run, then restart Android Studio.

Comment: It works! It turns out that the AVD connection did not refresh properly. The app needs to be refreshed like you said. Turn off and on

Answer (score 8):

I also faced this issue. I wiped out data from AVD manager and it is working fine after wiping out data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Free up some space in the Avd folder. Delete unnecessary virtual devices, which might take LOT'S of space. You can also free up some space in general in drive.
2. Make sure Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator is installed
3. Make sure that the needed SDK is installed (for the virtual device you're using). Just see that the API of that virtual device is installed in: File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try quiting the emulator. Then in AVD Manager under your problem device click on the down triangle in Actions column and select 'Cold Boot Now'.

Answer (score 0):

Running Android Studio 4.1.2, and this still seems to be an issue from time to time.
I found that running `adb kill-server` solved my issue, rather than the other suggestions here. No need to wipe data, cold boot, or restart Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Do three things

1. check the Android virtual devicve (AVD) is installed . file-> setting ->appearance and behavior -> android sdk
2. Check the installed andoid is only used while running . I had installed android11 but my AVD was running noughat7.1.1
3. Wipe out data from AVD manager . Dont worry only temp memory will be vacated n no any installed sw will go.

After doing this mine problem of
"running on no device " is gone . Enjoy